# Why do I don't get no data back from the array?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I don't get the correct data back. What is my mistake?

```
  var ref = firebase.database().ref("Entries/kategorie");
  ref.once("value")
    .then(function(snapshot) {
      $scope.tmp = snapshot.val();
      $scope.$apply(function () {
      $scope.data = $scope.tmp
      // returns what you see in the image
      console.log($scope.tmp.catname);
      // The Log statement returns ["Cat1", "Cat2", "Cat3"] so the                   array which i need. 
      })

    });
```

This is what i get back.

[image]

This is the html

```
<div ng-repeat="cat in data" class="animated lightSpeedIn">
  <a nav-transition="none"><div ng-style="{'background': 'url(' + cat.bgurl + ')','background-repeat': 'no-repeat','background-size': 'cover','display': 'block','width': '100%','height': '25vh' }" class="bgcat center">
    <div class="inner">
      <h1>{{cat.catname}}</h1>
      <h4>{{cat.subtitle}}</h4>
    </div>
  </div></a>
</div>
```

I thought with `cat.catname` it's possible to get the catnameurl. But that seems to be wrong...

Answer (score 0):

You do have a very "unusual" data model. But I leave that up to you. Based on your data model, your html should look like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="bgurl in data.bgurl" class="animated lightSpeedIn">
  <a nav-transition="none"><div ng-style="{'background': 'url(' + bgurl + ')','background-repeat': 'no-repeat','background-size': 'cover','display': 'block','width': '100%','height': '25vh' }" class="bgcat center">
  <div class="inner">
    <h1>{{data.catname[$index]}}</h1>
    <h4>{{data.subtitle[$index]}}</h4>
</div>
```

I would recommend that you structure your data like this (attention: this structure does not fit the HTML that I just proposed in this answer)

```
[
  {bgurl:'abc', catname:'name1', subtitle:'my first cat'},
  {bgurl:'xyz', catname:'name2', subtitle:'my second cat'}
]
```

Comment: Exactly, but in this html line your are assuming it to be an array: <div ng-repeat="cat in data" class="animated lightSpeedIn">. Try the html that I just posted.

Comment: @schacki i have to loop trough the data

Comment: Please provide a) the output of console.log($scope.tmp) to see the complete data; and b), what you actually want to be displayed in html.

Comment: How should i structure the data? Could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Your returned data is in little bit incorrect format. The correct way is to return array of objects

But, you can do this:

```
<div ng-repeat="catname in data.catname" class="animated lightSpeedIn">
  <a nav-transition="none"><div ng-style="{'background': 'url(' + data.bgurl[$index] + ')','background-repeat': 'no-repeat','background-size': 'cover','display': 'block','width': '100%','height': '25vh' }" class="bgcat center">
    <div class="inner">
      <h1>{{catname}}</h1>
      <h4>{{cat.subtitle[$index]}}</h4>
    </div>
  </div></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. I can't use this because i have different data i have to show. I would have to use multiple ng-repeats. Could you help me, how i should structure the data, that i only have to use one ng-repeat and get all? Is it not possible to use arrays? This is my data structure right now. http://pasteboard.co/3l2IT99TS.png

Comment: A correct returned data structure should looks like this `Array[{catname: 'catname', subtitle: 'subtitle', bgurl: 'bgurl' },{catname: 'catname', subtitle: 'subtitle', bgurl: 'bgurl' }, ...]`